# Duplicate ANY transaction from Bitcoin to Bitcoin Cash.. is it possible?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

After the hard fork happened on 1 August and Bitcoin Cash was created the blockchain diverged in two. Any transaction before 1 August made on the main blockchain now is available on Bitcoin Cash chain.

**So my question is:**

What will happen if I random pick any transaction from the bitcoin blockchain **after** 1 August from random block and push it to Bitcoin Cash nodes? Will this transaction get approved?

Answer (score 1):

No, transaction will not be approved. There are differences in transaction format. Transactions are not valid between 2 forks.